# simple svg object reset at end of path

Tags: svg, svg-animate

This is probably really simple but I am starting to learn svg and am confused by the behavior of the following code:

```
<svg>
<defs>
    <path id="thepath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M25,0 L200,200" />
</defs>
<rect x="25" y="0" width="50" height="100" fill="slategrey">
      <animateTransform id="one"
                        attributeType="xml"
                        attributeName="transform"
                        type="rotate"
                        from="0 50 50"
                        to="360 50 50"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite" 
                        end ="onemove.end"/>

    <animateMotion id="onemove" dur="3s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#thepath"/>
    </animateMotion>
</rect>
```

What I am expecting to happen is the rectangle rotate in a circle on a center point. Which it does.

I expect it to also travel down the path. Which it does.

I expect it to stop rotating once it is down the path. Which I think it does.

I expect it to stay at the end of the path. Which it does not.

It resets to the start point and has stopped rotation. So I am not sure if the reset stopped the rotation or the actual end statement stopped rotation.

So my question is two fold: why does it reset and how do I prevent that.

Also, any links to good svg tutorials would be appreciated. While I am finding a lot tutorials, I think I am not finding quality because I have a feeling this is a very simple issue I should already know from my research.

I think I need something in the path to prevent the reset but I have no idea what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `fill="freeze"` to the `<animateMotion>` so it will freeze the effect at the end. See: [SVG - Chapter 19 Animation, Timing Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#TimingAttributes):

```
<animateMotion id="onemove" dur="3s" fill="freeze">
    <mpath xlink:href="#thepath"/>
</animateMotion>
```

See it working here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/Sy647/)

There is a [W3C SVG Tutorial](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Offices/Presentations/SVG/) written in SVG. A very good community-maintained [SVG Tutorial at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial) and the [SVG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) itself which is very readable and has many examples. It's the best reference, but you should also try out everything in different browsers using CodePen or JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it was simple. I will check out those resources tomorrow.